# regex (preg_replace) match word except where it starts a sentence/paragraph

Tags: php, regex

Im currently scratching my head to figure out a way to match a word except where it starts a sentence or paragraph.

I have a large amount of text where i need to lowercase the start of a set word, apart from if it starts a sentence

so far i have

```
preg_replace('/Word\b/','word',$text);
```

Can someone please help with the exclusion pattern of starting a sentence

thanks

Comment: What do you want to match, please make some examples!

Comment: Quite unclear. Could you show some input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on how you define a sentence.

```
preg_replace('/([^.?!]\s*)Word\b/','$1word',$text);
```

This ensures that the word does not immediately follow some punctuation. It also means that it can't match the start of a paragraph because it needs to match some non-punctuation character before it.

Comment: I think you would need to change the `s*` to `s+` for it to do what you think it does, but even then, it wouldn't do what you think it does.

Comment: It should be `\s*` because it's possible that there are no spaces since the last punctuation (also, at the start of a paragraph)